# Traversal issue in navigation(which is shared across application) bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

Since my application had same navigation bar across application, I thought of implementing shared navigation bar across application.

```
My project structure is a follows
    Login
    |-Login.html, Login.css, Login.js
    Home
    |-Home.html, Home.css, Home.js
    Test
    |-Project.html, Project.css, Project.js
         Test1
            |-Test1.html, Test1.css, Test1.js
         Test2
            |-Test2.html, Test2.css, Test2.js
    |-Temp
        |-Temp.html, Temp.css, Temp.js
    |-Shared
        |-Shared.html, Shared.css, Shared.js, navigation.html
```

Here is my navigation.html which I have kept inside shared folder.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item ">
                  <a class="nav-link" 
                  href="../Home/Home.html"
                  >Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" 
                      href="../Employee/CreateEmployee.html"
                  >Employee</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
                      id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                  >Test</a>

                  <div class="dropdown-menu"   
                      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a  
                          class="dropdown-item" 
                          href="../Test/Test1/NewCQ.html"
                      >Create New CQ</a>
                      <a 
                          class="dropdown-item" 
                          href="../Test/Test2/Test2.html"
                      >Update CQ</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" 
                      href="../Temp/Temp.html"
                  >Temp</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link float-right" href="../Login/Login.html"
                  >Logout</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

This is how I have created div in respective html files

```html
<div class="row border-bottom border-dark">
    <div class="col px-0">
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <div id="navigationBar">

        </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

When respective page visits I am loading that navigation.html file in shared.js from shared folder which I have imported in all the pages.

```
//Load navigation.html from shared folder
$(function(){
    $("#navigationBar").load("../Shared/navigation.html");
});
```

The issue here is that

1. relative paths will be different from different pages, so how do i need to provide the relative paths inside navigation.html
2. $("#navigationBar").load("../Shared/navigation.html"); is not loading inside Test.html(its beacuse of relative path) when redirect from home.html

please let me know if am doing anything wrong here. waiting for your responses. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, why use relative paths at all? Just use an absolute path in your links.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/folder/Test/Test2/Test2.html">Update CQ</a>
```

You'll need to have some more javascript detecting the current path and figuring out the relative path from there, but that's a lot of work to do for no real gain  unless you have a very specific reason to use relative paths.